# Make a push file inside of docker

Tags: node.js, github

i would like send a gif to github, but i cannot try a solution how do this.

```
const TextOnGif = require('text-on-gif');

let req = 'test';
(async function () {
let v = `https://media0.giphy.com/media/Ju7l5y9osyymQ/giphy.gif`;

console.log(`${v}`);
//create a TextOnGif object
var gif = new TextOnGif({
    file_path: v,
    //path to local file, url or Buffer
});


 gif.font_color = 'white';
 gif.font_size = `${25+(2.12*req.length)}px`;
 gif.stroke_color = 'black';
 gif.stroke_width = 5;
 //write as file
 await gif.textOnGif({
    text: `${req}`,
    get_as_buffer: false, //set to false to save time
    write_path: "gif-with-text.gif"
 });

 //res.send(gif);
})();
```

I need insert first the credencials (email and username) to send the gif to my repository.

Thanks